# Hide my server public ip

Tags: web-applications, dns, ip

I created a server in which I installed a web application based on an SQL Server database. The application uses IIS.

I want to access this web application from the net, so I opened a NAT port in my router, but to access the application I use my public address.

Example: http://41.224.257.253/webapp

I want to have a web address, and hide that IP.
What should I do? How to publish that application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `domain name`, and configure `DNS` to your server address.

[Here](https://www.thesitewizard.com/domain/point-domain-name-website.shtml) you have an "how to" do it. If you want use your own server for the site remember keep it always "on line". Another option is use one hosting service.

The previus link have a lot of information about it.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you, this is very usefull , yes it helps, i must get a domain then configure it.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide IP with external VPN/proxy, but you can also mask (cloak) it by using for example DUC client with noip.com IP mask dynamic DNS. More [here](http://www.noip.com/remote-access).

Comment: Thank you, this is very usefull